# Macbook is slow when connected to Internet!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi, mojave

Once I connect to Internet (WiFi) suddenly everything on my Macbook acts like it's frozen when opening Apps... and every app I try to open takes 20+ seconds!

But as soon as I turn off WiFi or connect through a VPN, the issue is fixed!

Videos below:

1. When I don't have Internet connection and everything is fine:
   https://streamable.com/6dmqd
2. When I connect to Internet:
   https://streamable.com/13eei

Why does this happen and is there a way around it?

macOS is 10.14.6 and I've already tried fresh OS installation.

**Edit:** I see a lot of "**trustd**" errors in console, but even though it is allowed, LittleSnitch Firewall doesn't show any outgoing connection from trustd at all!

`trustd` errors (these 3 errors keep repeating in this order):

- load failed with error code=-1001
- finished with error - code: -999
- HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])

I have also tried with an iPad and Windows machine, and they work just fine!

And tried this with another Macbook Air (2018) and it has the exact same issue!

Comment: Does activity monitor show something too? Also post those errors you talk about.

Comment: @ankii Activity monitor shows nothing out of the ordinary, added errors.

Comment: @ankii Is there a way I can disable `trustd` to check if that's causing the issue?

Comment: Does this happen when you connect to other WiFi networks at other locations?

Comment: Disabling trustd would be a bad idea. "trustd provides services for evaluating trust in certificates for all processes on the system." The issue may be certificate-related.